# How can I extract/parse from this SOAP envelope using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, soap

I am using a gem which uses soap/wsdlDriver.

When I post I get back a SOAP response and am unable to easily parse it.

This is the response I get back:

```
#<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x159e95faf098 {}id="27b907f8-da51-f611-ab02-4c5f88a8ec8
8" {}error=#<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x159e95fae33c {}number="0" {}name="No Error"
 {}description="No Error">>
```

I need to get the entire value in the id="xxxx"

This is what on get on heroku (note: it works locally).  This comes from testing various variations of response.id (where response.inspect is what created the output above)

> f"
>   {}error=#>
>   response[id]
>   /disk1/home/slugs/220752_47a08bb_10e7/mnt/app/controllers/sugarcrm_controller.rb
>   :77: warning: Object#id will be
>   deprecated; use Object#object_id nil
>   response.id:
>   /disk1/home/slugs/220752_47a08bb_10e7/mnt/app/controllers/sugarcrm_controller.rb
>   :79: warning: Object#id will be
>   deprecated; use Object#object_id
>   23891500658740
>   /disk1/home/slugs/220752_47a08bb_10e7/mnt/app/controllers/sugarcrm_controller.rb
>   :80: warning: Object#id will be
>   deprecated; use Object#object_id this
>   is the contact_id: 23891500658740
>   events:

Comment: Is that the actual server response? Or is it the `inspect` value of some object?  Because it looks like this is a ruby instance of class `SOAP::Mapping::Object`.  If so, I would bet it has some sort of API to access this data.  `object.attributes[:id]` or something perhaps.

Comment: Hmmm...I need to check I don't remember.  Looking at the code now....how can I find out how to access the data?  I tried response.id and it didn't work (where response = SOAP CALL)

Comment: yes, you are right, it is an .inspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm 95% sure that is the output of [`SOAP::Mapping::Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/soap/rdoc/classes/SOAP/Mapping/Object.html#M003837) and not the actual response.  And from that class it looks you use the `[]` method to pull out attributes.

So if I am reading that right, then it looks like you might want:

```
response_id = response_object['id']
```

Though each attribute being prefaced with `{}` seems pretty odd.  So if that is actually part of the attribute name, you may need:

```
response_id = response_object['{}id']
```

But that seems pretty strange, and may indicate that the SOAP library you are using is not parsing the response properly.

*Disclaimer: I've never used this lib before, and posted this from just perusing the docs...  This may or may not be very accurate in the ways using this class is described.*

Comment: Yes, that's what I was hoping...but what I get is a different string when I do it.  It works locally, but when I heroku, instead of the alpha-numeric string, all I get is a string of numbers, which isn't correct...thoughts?

Comment: Here is the output I get on heroku versus local:

Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id 

Perhaps that will shed some light?

Comment: It might be a different version of ruby or the SOAP lib causing it to behave in 2 different ways.

Comment: Hi, how could I check -- I believe we're both on ruby 1.8.7...ah, wait, the other app is still on the old one...ah, yeah, that's it

Comment: I just checked it on the new heroku stack -- still getting the error :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with ruby, but may be like this code in javascript.

```
var t = "<SOAP message........>";
var id = t.replace(/.*id=\"(.*?)\".*/, "$1");
```

Regex details:

```
.*id=\"(.*?)\".*

.* = anything, 0 or N times.
(.*?) = anything, 0 or N times, stopping at first match.
$1 = first group, the content inside ().
```

So, everthing will be replaced by id content.